# Alternative to Plist file(iphone) in blackberry application

Tags: blackberry

I have a iphone application developed, and now i want to replicate the same iphone application on blackberry.
In the existing application iphone application, we have the plist file, where we maintain certain values like server address, map url etc. All default values are saved in plist. 
Please can you give me an alternative similar to plist in blackberry.

Answer (score 1):

I usually just parse it like xml and use what the iPhone guys give me in .plist format :)